# Replacing Eidolons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, eidolon

My character recently got in a fight with her Eidolon and now she refuses to obey orders so i wanted to ask. Is it possible to replace an Eidolon with another Eidolon?

Comment: Over what were the two of you fighting?

Comment: My Eidolon was engaged in a duel against another person and she won but the party needed information from the guy so i ordered her to stop  which she did not take kindly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completely replacing an Eidolon is, according to the Advanced Player's Guide, Ultimate Magic and Ultimate Campaign, not possible. However, an Eidolon is inherently loyal to their summoner. While it will not obey commands that will hurt it just because or are otherwise spiteful, it will obey regular commands, even those who would otherwise hurt it when it would achieve a goal. So the best way to solve this issue is (just like in real life) not with violence or by avoiding the issue, but talking over your differences and settle them that way. Also, make sure that your DM knows that this is how Eidolons function.